# Audio Units sound check feature effect

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, signal-processing, audiounit

I am using Audio Units to create a music(voice) App.
The app is going to have speakers(like in a interview) and a background music.

What I need is *balancing the volume* of the speakers, to make it feel like everybody is talking with the same tone.

There is a same feature in iOS Music App called **[Sound Check](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201724)**.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assuming the speakers are separate inputs, you may want to have a look at [the ITU-R BS.1770](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.1770-4-201510-I!!PDF-E.pdf) (possibly disregarding the part about multi-channels which likely does not apply if you have a single output).

Comment: Yes, I will have a single output. Basically this algorithm is what I need to do in theory but I couldn't find any specific example produced in iOS. Thank you

Comment: @ArbenPnishi hello sir have find any solution for this on cuz i want to achieve the same thing as your question describe